# How to limit number of connections to a database in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring based application, deployed on the Tomcat server. What I need is to limit the maximum number of simultaneous connections to a database. This is data source section from my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="..." />
  <property name="username" value="..." />
  <property name="password" value="..." />
</bean>
```

I would like to do it on the application level, not with server configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the [maxActive](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#maxActive) property on the dataSource.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I needed. Thanks!